# Python 3 in Jupyter Notebook doesn't work

Tags: python, jupyter

I want to use Jupyter Notebook with Python 3 (which according to my terminal it's the 3.7.4 version) but when I open Jupyter Notebook it shows me "Python 2" in the corner.
I first installed pip and after numerous tries someone told me "do it with conda and your problem will be fixed" and I did, but the problem is still there.

From what I have look in internet and what my profesor and friends told me, it should be working.

Any suggestions?

P.S.: I even read some questions asked here but the answers didn't work for me.

EDIT: Following @Fabioconcina suggestiong, maybe helpful to show what I obtain by using `jupyter --paths` in the terminal.

So I got the following:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob4nB.jpg)

Comment: Can you run `jupyter --paths` from terminal? So we check which Jupyter installation are you using.

Comment: @fabioconcina done!

config:
    /Users/unperrito/.jupyter
    /Users/unperrito/opt/anaconda3/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/unperrito/Library/Jupyter
    /Users/unperrito/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/unperrito/Library/Jupyter/runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your suggestions were right. What I had to do was to open a **new** file. In all yours suggestions I was opening the first file I was working. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed anaconda  you can update your python by using conda. Please run your terminal or command prombt as administrator, and just use any of the method given below

```
   1.   conda install python=$pythonversion$
```

or if  you just need any updated version of python

```
   2. conda update python
```

or

```
3. conda create --name py374 python=3.7.4 --channel conda-forge
```

Comment: I tried the first successfully but the problem is still there. I tried the second but I shows me "(base) Cargador:~ unperrito$ conda update python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - 

Updating python is constricted by 

anaconda -> requires python==3.7.4=h359304d_1

If you are sure you want an update of your package either try `conda update --all` or install a specific version of the package you want using `conda install <pkg>=<version>`

done"

Answer (score 0):

Using the `where` command in windows (and, I think `which` in linux/mac) can help diagnose this problem.  For instance, if I run

```
> where python
```

on my computer, I get the following response

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

I can use this to track down what my computer wants to run if I type in other commands, for instance:

```
> where jupyter
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter.exe
```

will help me sus out what particular executable is being run when I type a command.

---

It is worth investigating what version of ipython you have installed as well, since that will affect what python kernels you can support.  The [ipython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html) notes that

> IPython 6.0 stopped support for Python 2, so installing IPython on Python 2 will give you an older version (5.x series).

which suggests to me that you're running a pre-6.0 version.  You can use `conda list` to list out the versions of everything you have installed.

Comment: In fact, using `which python` I got `/Users/unperrito/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`. About the second mention, using `conda list` I got that my iPython version is 7.8.0.

Comment: you mentioned that you're using conda.  when you start jupyter, have you activated the correct venv before starting jupyter?  or are you using the base venv?  also, what do you get if you run `echo $PATH`?

Comment: I just open the terminal and write "jupyter notebook", I'm quite begginer =(. I wrote `echo $PATH` and I got `/Users/unperrito/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/unperrito/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin` I hope it be useful.

Comment: @UnPerrito, try running `source activate` from your command prompt.  Your prompt should change from something like `computername:folder user$` to `(source) computername:folder user$ `.  If you get to that point, try starting jupyter again and see if you get a different kernel version (python 3 instead of 2).

Comment: @ReginRoosevelt I did it and it is still on Python 2... =(

Comment: if you do `source activate` and then `python --version`, what do you get?

Comment: related: I sent an email to your academic email address with my discord.  LMK if you want to chat in person.